# How do I see battery usage after a complete drain?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, battery-life

I'm having the classic problem of sudden battery drain, but the twist is that I can never catch it in the act. I just find my phone dead when I pick it up to use. When I go to the Battery section of Settings, I discover that apparently a complete drain resets the battery usage statistics, rendering them useless. What to do?

I'm running CyanogenMod 11 milestone build (Android 4.4.4) on Galaxy S2 without Google Apps.

Comment: 1) I have never run a build of CyanogenMod on any of about 11 devices without bugs, errors and just random weirdness. 2) Is the battery itself damaged/bloated? Can you try a different battery and see? Can you try another ROM maybe? If it's the original battery from the device I'd say it's past it's best. You'd expect about 500 charge/discharge cycles. Something like better battery stats saves log files, but is a paid app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats&hl=en

Comment: 1) Stock firmware for SGS2 is worse - that's why I went to CyanogenMod in the first place. 2) The battery is brand new from [Anker](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/accessories/battery-anker-1900mah-t1273125). Since I don't have Google Apps, I can't get paid Play Store apps. I can get free ones with some hacking though.

Comment: You could flash gapps in a few seconds... No need to not have it. Yeah the stock firmware is laggy and slow, but it doesn't generally crap out altogether like CM. So far with 3 devices here I've had: No GPS, no WiFi, screen flickering, random reboots, crashes, black screen of death, corrupted partitions and it goes on like this. I'd say a different ROM would be a starting point. Non Samsung batteries I don't know much about but they can be poor quality, I don't know that particular manufacturer so I can't comment on that.

Comment: You could try installing an automation app that would audibly alert you (or send you an email, etc) when the battery got below X%. Then you could check the stats *before* the phone died.